# How do I create an empty csv file on a specific folder?

Tags: python

I had a doubt on how to create an empty csv file where I can open it later to save some data using python. How do I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

An empty csv file can be created like any other file - you just have to perform any operation on it. With bash, you can do `touch /path/to/my/file.csv`.

Note that you do not have to create an empty file for python to write in. Python will do so automatically if you write to a non-existing file. In fact, creating an empty file from within python means to open it for writing, but not writing anything to it.

```
with open("foo.csv", "w") as my_empty_csv:
  # now you have an empty file already
  pass  # or write something to it already
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also use Pandas to do the same as below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list())
df.to_csv('empty_csv.csv')
```

After creating above file you can Edit exported file as per your requirement.