# Creating new text documents that have not existed before

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I am using python to create a program that takes attendance. I want it to create a new text document each day that is saved as the date of that day. I know how to write into a file that already exists, but do not know how to create a new one through python. I also do not know how to make it create a new one each new day. Thanks guys!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. As it stands this answer is likely to be downvoted or flagged as it is not showing any effort, or asking specific questions about programming. For better results, show examples of your code with what you are trying to achieve and what error you are encountering.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create an empty csv file on a specific folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162253/how-do-i-create-an-empty-csv-file-on-a-specific-folder)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily, you just need to provide the date as filename which can be calculated like

```
import time
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
with open(timestr, 'w+') as f:
    f.write('XXXXX')
    # Write what further needed
```

A file will be created with the proper timestamp.